# add script in function.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to put my script in my function.php on my Wordpress but I don't found how to do it. Need help!

here's..:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

       $(function() {

           $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
               rows        : 3,
               columns     : 5,
               animType    : 'fadeInOut',
               animSpeed   : 500,
               interval    : 1200,
               step        : 1,
               w320        : {
                   rows    : 3,
                   columns : 5
               },
               w240        : {
                   rows    : 3,
                   columns : 5
               }
           } );

       });
   </script>
```

Thx.

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone! Take this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: This link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882341/basic-php-question-adding-javascript-to-php-page

Comment: sounds like you need to use a template file rather than functions.php, look in your themes folder for the header.php or footer.php file and add the script there

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress isn't that straightforward. For it to be so modular and user-friendly with plug-n-play, it has a complex structure.

There are different ways of adding scripts and it all depends on *when* they need to be available and/or executed.

Comment: This script need to be executed at the opening of my page. it's lead a custom bloc on my home page. i just don't know how to transform that script to put it in my function.php